# How to turn off the beep on save in Visual Studio Code?

Tags: powershell, visual-studio-code

Visual Studio code has a double beep when saving a file that's particularly penetrating when wearing headphones. There doesn't appear to be a setting for it in the settings.
I did find a suggestion that it can be done in PowerShell with:

```
Set-PSReadlineOption -BellStyle None
```

but entering this in the terminal window of VS Code returned an ObjectNotFoundError.

Edit: I've discovered the problem is with PowerShell. I have a PowerShell window open to run the Angular 5 website and it's this that is beeping.  I discovered this by switching to Visual Studio 2017 to edit the website and that happily beeped away on save too.

Comment: I ran `Set-Service beep -StartupType disabled` in PowerShell and rebooted the computer which did silence the beep, but I'm not sure at this stage what side-effects this may have had.